# Unknown wordpress http referrer error for user file upload

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress plugin user file upload. It shows repeated file upload fileds under /wp-admin/user-edit.php so admin can upload files to user account.

This works well till 139 files and after that its shows us an unknown error.

From this URL

```
/wp-admin/user-edit.php?user_id=20&wp_http_referer=%2xxxyz.com%2Fwp-admin%2Fusers.php%3Fpaged%3D2
```

Its going to this below URL only for the 139 no. file.

```
/wp-admin/user-edit.php
```

We have consulted with so many wordpress consultant but there is no luck. We had also increased  the wp memory to 256M and max execution time.

[image]

When I viewed the source I got these things.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Ticket #11289, IE bug fix: always pad the error page with enough characters such that it is greater than 512 bytes, even after gzip compression abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890aabbccddeeffgghhiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz11223344556677889900abacbcbdcdcededfefegfgfhghgihihjijikjkjlklkmlmlnmnmononpopoqpqprqrqsrsrtstsubcbcdcdedefefgfabcadefbghicjkldmnoepqrfstugvwxhyz1i234j567k890laabmbccnddeoeffpgghqhiirjjksklltmmnunoovppqwqrrxsstytuuzvvw0wxx1yyz2z113223434455666777889890091abc2def3ghi4jkl5mno6pqr7stu8vwx9yz11aab2bcc3dd4ee5ff6gg7hh8ii9j0jk1kl2lmm3nnoo4p5pq6qrr7ss8tt9uuvv0wwx1x2yyzz13aba4cbcb5dcdc6dedfef8egf9gfh0ghg1ihi2hji3jik4jkj5lkl6kml7mln8mnm9ono
-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>WordPress &rsaquo; Error</title>

</head>
<body id="error-page">
    <p>Invalid user ID.</p></body>
</html>
```

The function in my Plugins file

```
 //change upload directory
    public function user_upload_files_dir($upload) {
        //check if this a user-edit page
        $current_page = basename($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        $current_page_tmp = explode("?", $current_page);
        $current_page = $current_page_tmp[0];
        if ($current_page != "user-edit.php")
            return $upload;

        // check if it a async-upload request
        $referer = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        if ($referer != "async-upload.php")
            return $upload;

        //get userid from http http_referer
        $p = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        parse_str($p["query"], $get);
        $user_id = $get['user_id'];

        //change upload directory to user-files/$user_id
        $baseDir = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/user-files/';
        $baseUrl = WP_CONTENT_URL . '/uploads/user-files/';
        $upload['subdir'] = $user_id;
        $upload['path'] = $baseDir . $upload['subdir'];
        $upload['url'] = $baseUrl . $upload['subdir'];

        return $upload;
    }

    //Enqueue class assets
    public function enqueue() {
        global $pagenow;
        if ($pagenow != "user-edit.php")
            return;
        // Enqueue styles
        wp_enqueue_style('bhuufu_admin_styles', BHUUFU_URL . '/assets/css/admin_styles.css');
        // Enqueue scripts
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('bhuufu_repeatable-fields.js', BHUUFU_URL . '/assets/js/repeatable-fields.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('bhuufu_admin_script', BHUUFU_URL . 'assets/js/stb_admin.js');
        // Hook to add/remove files
        do_action('BHUUFU/assets/enqueue');
    }

    //conditionally_add_scripts_and_styles
    public function conditionally_add_scripts_and_styles($posts) {

        if (empty($posts))
            return $posts;
        $shortcode_found = false;
        foreach ($posts as $post) {

            if (stripos($post->post_content, '[list_user_files]') !== false) {
                $shortcode_found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($shortcode_found) {
            wp_enqueue_style('user-upload-css', BHUUFU_URL . 'assets/css/styles.css');
        }

        return $posts;
    }

    //user_file_upload_fields
    function add_user_file_upload_fields($user) {
        $bhu_uufef = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'user_file_uploads', true);
        wp_enqueue_media();
        ?>
        <h3><?php _e('File Uploads', 'wpcf7'); ?></h3>
        <div class="ff-repeatable">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><?php _e('Url', 'wpcf7'); ?></th>
                        <th><?php _e('Name', 'wpcf7'); ?></th>
                        <th><?php _e('Decsription', 'wpcf7'); ?></th>
                        <th><img alt="Add Row" class="ff-add-row" src="<?php echo BHUUFU_URL; ?>assets/images/add.png"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="ff-add-template" style="">
                        <td><input type="text" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_url_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_url" value="" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_name_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_name" value="" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_description_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_description" value="" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="hidden" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_id_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_id" value="" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_oname_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_oname" value="" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_mime_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_mime" value="" />
                            <input class="button _unique_name_button" name="_unique_name_button" value="Select File" />
                            <img alt="Remove Row" class="ff-remove-row" src="<?php echo BHUUFU_URL; ?>assets/images/remove.png">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    if (isset($bhu_uufef['file_url']) && $extra_fields = array_filter($bhu_uufef['file_url'])) {
                        foreach ($extra_fields as $key => $value) {
                            echo'<tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_url_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_url" value="' . $bhu_uufef['file_url'][$key] . '" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_name_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_name" value="' . $bhu_uufef['file_name'][$key] . '" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_description_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_description" value="' . $bhu_uufef['file_description'][$key] . '" /></td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_id_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_id" value="' . $bhu_uufef['file_id'][$key] . '" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_oname_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_oname" value="' . $bhu_uufef['file_oname'][$key] . '" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_mime_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_mime" value="' . $bhu_uufef['file_mime'][$key] . '" />
                        <input class="button _unique_name_button" name="_unique_name_button" value="Select File" />
                        <img alt="Remove Row" class="ff-remove-row" src="' . BHUUFU_URL . 'assets/images/remove.png">
                        </td>
                    </tr>';
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo'
                     <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_url_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_url" value="" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_name_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_name" value="" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_description_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_description"  value="" /></td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_id_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_id" value="" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_oname_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_oname" value="" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_mime_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_mime" value="" />
                        <input class="button _unique_name_button" name="_unique_name_button" value="Select File" />
                        <img alt="Remove Row" class="ff-remove-row" src="' . BHUUFU_URL . 'assets/images/remove.png">
                        </td> 
                    </tr>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </tbody>            
            </table>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    //user porfile fields save
        public function save_user_file_upload_fields($user_id) {
            if (isset($_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_url_tmp']) && $extra_fields = array_filter($_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_url_tmp'])) {
                foreach ($extra_fields as $key => $value) {
                    $_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_url'][] = $_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_url_tmp'][$key];
                    $_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_name'][] = $_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_name_tmp'][$key];
                    $_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_description'][] = $_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_description_tmp'][$key];
                    $_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_id'][] = $_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_id_tmp'][$key];
                    $_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_oname'][] = $_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_oname_tmp'][$key];
                    $_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_mime'][] = $_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_mime_tmp'][$key];
                }
            }
            unset($_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_url_tmp']);
            unset($_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_name_tmp']);
            unset($_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_description_tmp']);
            unset($_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_id_tmp']);
            unset($_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_oname_tmp']);
            unset($_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_mime_tmp']);
            update_usermeta($user_id, 'user_file_uploads', $_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']);
        }

    //delete file
    public function deletefile() {
        global $wpdb;
        $file_id = $_REQUEST["file_id"];
        $user_id = $_REQUEST["user_id"];

        // Delete file
        $is_deleted = wp_delete_attachment($file_id);
        if ($is_deleted->ID) {
            $bhu_uufef = get_user_meta($user_id, 'user_file_uploads', true);
            $key = array_search($file_id, $bhu_uufef['file_id']);
            unset($bhu_uufef['file_url'][$key]);
            unset($bhu_uufef['file_name'][$key]);
            unset($bhu_uufef['file_description'][$key]);
            unset($bhu_uufef['file_id'][$key]);
            unset($bhu_uufef['file_oname'][$key]);
            unset($bhu_uufef['file_mime'][$key]);
            update_usermeta($user_id, 'user_file_uploads', $bhu_uufef);
            $result['status'] = "sucess";
        } else {
            $result['status'] = "fail";
        }

        echo json_encode($result);

        exit;
    }
```